# why we inherit base class instead of creating an instance of base class

Tags: oop, inheritance

In OOP we inherit another class for reusing code, but we also can reuse by creating an instance of Base Class. Whats will wrong?

For example:

```
//base class
Class A {
 // code
}


Class B {
//creating an instance instead of inheriting
 A objectOfA = new A();
// rest code
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that anything is wrong?

Comment: No, i don't think anything wrong, but from my curiosity I wanna know

Answer (score 1):

As [the Gang of Four writes](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/dp):

> Favor object composition over class inheritance.

The code example in the OP is an example of what that means. That's a good idea. Don't use inheritance for reuse.

In many languages (e.g. C#, Java) a class can only inherit from one base class. This means that if you've decided to inherit from a particular base class, you can't inherit from any other base class. If you use inheritance for code reuse, this entails that you can only reuse 'up' one particular inheritance tree, but not any other hierarchy. That's not particularly flexible.

In other languages that *do* support multiple inheritance, on the other hand, you run into the [diamond problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance).

Inheritance is, in general, problematic. There's usually better ways to achieve your goals that don't involve inheritance.